# a way of listing content using rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I am trying to list subject grade and version but I don`t know to how to iterate them ):

the result image is :

[image]

The classes is here:

```
class Subject

  has_many grades

  has_many versions

end
```

Now I want to list subject grade and version in the html page and the html code is here:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="span12">
    <table class="table table-bordered">

      <tbody>
        <tr  class="success">
          <td rowspan="4" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Subject</td>
          <td>Subject1</td>
          <td>Subject2</td>
          <td>Subject3</td>

          <td rowspan="4" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Grade</td>
          <td>Grade1</td>

          <td>Grade2</td>
          <td>Grade3</td>
          <td rowspan="4" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">Version</td>
          <td>Version1</td>
          <td>Version2</td>
          <td>Version3</td>


        </tr>
        <tr  class="success">
          <td>Subject4</td>
          <td>Subject5</td>
          <td>Subject6</td>
          <td>Grade4</td>
          <td>Grade5</td>
          <td>Grade6</td>

          <td>Version4</td>
          <td>Version5</td>
          <td>Version6</td>

        </tr>
        <tr   class="success">

          <td>Subject7</td>
          <td>Subject8</td>
          <td>Subject9</td>
          <td>Grade7</td>
          <td>Grade8</td>
          <td>Grade9</td>

          <td>Version7</td>
          <td>Version8</td>
          <td>Version9</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="success">

          <td>Subject10</td>
          <td>Subject11</td>
          <td>Subject12</td>
          <td>Grade10</td>
          <td>Grade11</td>
          <td>Grade12</td>

          <td>Version10</td>
          <td>Version11</td>
          <td>Version12</td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot that you're asking with this question, but the simple answer is you need to query all of them from ActiveRecord then you can use any of Ruby's built-in iterators like `Array#each` to loop through each and write out whatever HTML you need.

```
# in the controller...
@subjects = Subject.where(something)
@grades = Grade.where(something)
@versions = Version.where(something)

# in the view (ERB)...
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <td><%= subject.name %></td>
<% end %>

# in the view (HAML)...
- @subjects.each do |subject|
  %td= subject.name
```

Some tips:

- You could probably make it easier on yourself by using `display: inline-block` and not a table (assuming of course you're only supporting IE8+)
- Since the rendering of subjects/grades/versions is likely going to become identical, using a partial template there might be smart.  See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

If you absolutely must use a table, you can use `Array#each_slice` to partition the array.

```
# in the view (ERB)...
<% @subjects.each_slice(3) do |slice| %>
  <tr>
  <% slice.each do |subject| %>
    <td><%= subject.name %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in a tr column I will list three subjects three grades and three versions. if I use your code I will list all subjects in one tr ): and thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Where can I put tr and @grades.each_slice(3) ?

Comment: in between the each_slice and each

Comment: tr is ok now, but When I put @grades.each_slice(3) in the subject each_slice(3) I will get three subjects and all the grades in one tr.

Comment: Then don't put it in the subject.each_slice.

Comment: If I don`t put it in the subject.each_slice I will get three subject in one tr.While I want to get three subjects grades and versions in one tr ):